# Single Responsibility Principle: Responsibility unknown

Tags: c#, design, single-responsibility

I store sessions in a `SessionManager`. The session manager has a dependency to `ISessionPersister`.

**SessionManager**

```
private readonly ISessionPersister sessionPersister;
public SessionManager(ISessionPersister sessionPersister)
{
    this.sessionPersister = sessionPersister;
}
```

**ISessionPersister**

```
public interface ISessionPersister : IDisposable
{
    void PersistSessions(Dictionary<string, ISession> sessions);
}
```

**Q: If my application shuts down how / where do I call `PersistSessions`? Who is responsible?**

First Approach: Use Dispose in SessionManager

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
       if (this.sessionPersister != null && this.sessionMap != null && this.sessionMap.Count > 0)
       {
           this.sessionPersister.PersistSessions(this.sessionMap);
        }
    }
}
```

Is that the way to go or are there any better solutions?

Comment: Are you sure you want to save when application closes? What happens when HW crashes and application doesn't have time to save? I would recommend saving every time something changes.

Comment: "I store sessions in a SessionManager" that should be a SessionStorage then :] http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/03/i-shall-call-it-somethingmanager.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the type of application. In a WinForms application, for example, you could use the `Form.Closing` event of your main form. There is also an `Application.ApplicationExit` event, which works independently of any form.

Comment: So.. basically I should attach to an closing/shutdown event e.g. ApplicationExit. If ApplicationExit occours I would tell any shutdown relevant class (maybe abstracted by an interface like IShutdown) that shutdown is now happening. Right?

Comment: Yes. If your application is a long running one, you could also start a timer and additionally store the settings at predefined intervals.

Comment: I'm now using Quartz.NET to persist my sessions every n minutes. Thats good enough, I do not need a 100% reliable system. Session loss isn't that bad in the given environment. thanks for your time!